# Using alias inside Delete

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to run the following query (in reality it has more sense but just for the example I made it simple):

```
DELETE from my_tbl as a where a.id = 0;
```

But I keep getting

> Error: near "as": syntax error.

Is there any way around it? With `SELECT *` instead of `DELETE` it worked BTW

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use alias name for table inside delete statement as [delete statement works on single table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html). Also when you are using single table there seems to be no point of creating an alias. Simply do

```
DELETE from my_tbl  where id = 0;
```